# ADML files in foreign language

Tags: windows, group-policy, language

I have a centralized SYSVOL in my domain. Ofc it has en-EN language files (.adml) but the PC I am using to remotely administrate the domain is in Italian language (it-IT). Now, when I open the GPO editor on my PC I get everything in Italian, except that ADM templates tree which is displayed in english since it is read from the central storage. What am I supposed to do to fix this? Is copying %systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions\it-IT content to the sysvol enough or should I do something else? Also note that I run W8.1 and the domain controllers run WS2012 (not R2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can copy the `it-IT` folder from `%systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions\` to `\\domain.com\sysvol\domain\Policies\PolicyDefinitions\` and be able to use either Italian when configuring the ADMX settings from any computer connected to the domain. The ADM files are only in a single language, you can't change that.